# Grouped TableView selection problem

Tags: uitableview, ios4, selection

Ok, I have a grouped TableView that has the following overridden method:

-(NSIndexPath*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return nil;
}

... Obvious enough, to disable selection.

BUT!

If the user presses and holds on a cell, it gets highlighted (selected)!! I need to disable this, too.

On a side note, I am using the tableView to display static Data, almost like the About tableView in Settings > General. It just loads the info from an array of strings that I created manually.

If there is a better way to represent the data, please do tell!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `selectionStyle` property of the cell to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

See the documentation for `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to see why this is needed even though you're indicating that you don't want the cell selected.

Answer (score 1):

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

...did the trick.